# When I add a comment on YouTube it does not appear python selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I use the following code to add a comment on YouTube But when I add the comment, it does not appear after refreshing the page.
But when I comment in my personal browser, the comment appears normally
I think Google knows I'm using a non-personal browser so it doesn't show the comment
Is there an idea for the problem?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium_stealth import stealth
import time
import os
import pickle
urlVideo = str(input('Enter your URL video: '))

import io
with io.open('message.txt', "r", encoding="utf-8") as f:
    message = f.readlines()

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/90.0.4430.212 Safari/537.36")
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
options.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
options.add_argument('--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
stealth(driver,
    languages=["en-US", "en"],
    vendor="Google Inc.",
    platform="Win32",
    webgl_vendor="Intel Inc.",
    renderer="Intel Iris OpenGL Engine",
    fix_hairline=True,
    )

driver.get("https://www.youtube.com/")

#input('login and click start')
cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
for cookie in cookies:
    driver.add_cookie(cookie)

driver.get(urlVideo)
#click comments button
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body').send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
        time.sleep(0.5)
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="placeholder-area"]').click()
        driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="contenteditable-root"]').send_keys(message)
        break
    except:
        pass

time.sleep(2)
while True:
    try:
        driver.find_element_by_css_selector('.style-scope.ytd-button-renderer.style-primary.size-default').click()
        break
    except:
        pass

input('ok')
```

Comment: take a screenshot with selenium after you submit it (maybe wait a few seconds) ... its pretty possible google has bot detection stuff ... i cant imagine they like people automating comments

Comment: Do you mean to take a screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

Youtube detects using several flags for bots such as proxy score, selenium detection, user agent, past account activity etc.
you need to bypass all of this to trick youtube!
I made a youtube bot for a client and for that I did a lot of testing, that's why I know this.
you need to make your chrome driver undetectable and behave like a human not a bot.

Comment: hi sir how i can make chrome driver undetectable and behave like a human not a bot !

Comment: discord @odddkidout#3154

Comment: i dont have discord give me your twitter or instagram

Comment: same @odddkidout

Comment: i can send you message , my user in twitter is ( user.zahouani )